# Focus a textfield inside a list

Tags: javascript, extjs

The ExtJS docs describe a method `focus` for `textfields` that will either focus a textfield or return false: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/modern/Ext.field.Text.html#method-focus

Generally this seems to work just fine, but once the textfield that should be focused is inside a `list` (part of the `listitem`) the focus is immediately removed and set to the parent `listitem` container. Focus however returns true (the focus is actually on the field for a few ms).

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/315h shows this by example. The first button tries to focus the first textfield inside the list (which fails) and the second one focuses the field below the `list`.

Is there any way to prevent the `listitem` from becoming focused?

Code from the fiddle:

```js
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create({
            fullscreen: true,

            xtype: 'container',

            items: [{
                xtype: 'list',

                itemConfig: {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'component',
                        html: 'Row'
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        value: 'Focus Me'
                    }],
                    margin: '15px 0'
                },
                data: [{
                    title: 'Item 1'
                }, {
                    title: 'Item 2'
                }, {
                    title: 'Item 3'
                }, {
                    title: 'Item 4'
                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Try to focus',
                handler: function () {
                    this.up('container').down('list').down('textfield').focus();
                    Ext.toast(this.up('container').down('list').down('textfield').hasFocus + '');
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                itemId: 'focusable',
                value: 'Focusable'
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Try to focus',
                handler: function () {
                    this.up('container').down('#focusable').focus();
                    Ext.toast(this.up('container').down('#focusable').hasFocus + '');
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

On ExtJS 6.7 the first click on a textfield in a list does not even work but this seems to be fixed in 7.0.

Comment: Strangely using `focus(true)` (to select the text) works, but as you would expect it also selects the text of the input

Comment: Great find! Using `focus(true)` would actually be okay in the usecase this comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [defaultFocus](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/modern/Ext.Container.html#cfg-defaultFocus) for `listitem` container. Its work for me ([fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/318v)).

P.S. thank you for your fiddle example. few do it.

Comment: Yes that works, so I guess the issues is something like:
I try to focus an element inside the list from outside, so the focus is not on the list or a list item yet. Once the focus moves to the field the focus changes and the list is trying to focus the containing list item (I found this by debugging the issue). 

The focus is thereby set again but this time to whatever the `defaultFocus` of the list item suggests. I wouldn't expect that to happen in this case. Thanks anyways. I will open a ticket (so this gets fixed) and add one of the suggested solutions as a workaround.